# Enormous hprof file parsing "Java heap space"

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have to parse enormous hprof file(54GB) and I'm out of RAM(given 30GB). Is there a walkaround?

Or maybe there is a way to proces hprof file via terminal? I could run it on my production server if there is a way.

Edit: I forgot to mention I want to analyse it using Eclipse MAT.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try with JProfiler. It has a "bin/jpanalyze" command line executable that performs the analysis, you can then transfer the snapshot as well as the `.analysis` directory to your local machine and it will open quickly.